# SAS model to be integrated with SQL server 2008/2005

Tags: sql-server-2008, sas

i have to do analysis on the data. and I am planning to use SAS model for logical regression. Can I integrate SAS model with SQL server 2008. And can it generates the reports? Can anyone having any tutorial regarding this.

Comment: If you have SAS skills, I would suggest doing the reporting in SAS and accessing the data through a database connection.  Otherwise, you'll have to explain what you want as the output.  Are you trying to score a data set in the database?  Do you want to store the coefficients and fit statistics in the database?

Comment: I want to retrieve the data from the database as well as want to pass and use my parameters and coeffients in the database itself and want to generate a report which can be shown via website. Can that be done using Sql server 2008 and VS 2010

Comment: You'd better have the SAS/ACCESS ODBC license.  It costs an arm & a leg.  Check if you have it by calling `PROC SETINIT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS can certainly handle the modeling and generate a nice output using ODS. However, there is no way to "integrate" your SAS model with SQL Server 2008 (I'm honestly not even sure what you mean by that).

You can use PROC SQL and ODBC connections to query the server for the data, then run the model and produce the output using ODS HTML, which can be put on a website.

Comment: Hi @TARehman Thank you for your help. I am new to R and SAS. I am planning to use R(Since its an open source)/SAS and by input of the data requiring the analysis results which to be displayed on ASP.net website.